# Unicode on older sdk

Tags: java, android, unicode, sdk

i got a question about Unicode Chars in Android.

I figured out how to display them, for example:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("\uD83C\uDFCC Golf \uD83C\uDFCC"));
```

But this will only be viewed if the SDK is high enough, for older Versions it just shows nothing.

My question is now, is there a way to show or load these unicode chars on older devices / older sdks?

Or do i need a work around with images, which would be really annyoing...

Greetz :)

Comment: You don't need to use `Html.fromHtml()`, especially since you are not actually giving it any HTML entities to decode. `\u` is a standard escape sequence in Java: `textView.setText("\uD83C\uDFCC Golf \uD83C\uDFCC");`

Comment: Well...yes, but that doesn't matter. On older devices this isn't working either...

Comment: U+1F3CC was introduced in Unicode 7.0, and was added in Android 7 Nouget. There is no option to use it in earlier versions.